# AngularJS and Bootstrap: ng-repeat causing list to lose formatting

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm attempting to have a ng-repeat that is retrieving content from an array and displaying it on a list. The content was originally JSON, but has been stringified before being pushed into the array.

The issue is that in bootstrap, this causes the list to lose it's formatting as so:

[image]

While, I would like it to look as so:

[image]

Here is my code for the dropdown component:

```
<li>
    <a ng-controller="appCtrl" href="#">{{greeting.text}}, world</a>
</li>

<div ng-controller="PostsCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="eachResponse in response.text">
        <a href="#">{{eachResponse}}</a>
    </li>
</div>

<li>
    <a href="#Mytemplate">My dropdown</a>
</li>
```

And my code for the function that returns an array from a JSON to the response.text in the 'PostsCtrl' controller used above:

```
function parseTheResponse(responsedataJSON) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(responsedata));
    var array = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < obj.connectors.length; i++ ){
        stringArray.push(JSON.stringify(obj.connectors[i].name));
    }

    return stringArray;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of `<div>` inside `<ul>`. Try moving ng-controller to `<ul>` and removing that `<div>` wrapper.

Like the following:

```
<ul ng-controller="PostsCtrl">

    <li>
        <a ng-controller="appCtrl" href="#">{{greeting.text}}, world</a>
    </li>

    <li ng-repeat="eachResponse in response.text">
        <a href="#">{{eachResponse}}</a>
    </li>

    <li>
        <a href="#Mytemplate">My dropdown</a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

PS. Looks like you are moving on with your `hello world` app (taking a look at your previous questions). Good work!

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for your help and encouraging words!